# Tracking User-Defined `struct` Members with a Designated Initializer Syntax

Tags: unit-testing, c++11, c-preprocessor, c99

For a unit-testing library that I'm writing, [rexo](https://github.com/christophercrouzet/rexo), I would like to implement an automatic test registration mechanism compatible with both C99 and C++11.

Automatic test registration usually goes along the lines of:

- providing macros for the users to define test suites and test cases.
- having the macros instantiate file-level structures that contain the data needed to fully describe their respective test suites/cases.
- having some logic that can somehow discover these structure instances at run-time.

I've got most of this sorted out but one bit: providing a nice interface for defining additional data to be attached to each test suite/case.

The (non-public) data structure to attach looks like this:

```c
struct rx__data {
    const char *name;
    int value;
    rx_run_fn run;
};
```

I managed to get a `RX__MAKE_DATA()` macro working with a designated initializer syntax, as follows:

```c
/* https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro ----------------------------------- */

#define EVAL0(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EVAL1(...) EVAL0(EVAL0(EVAL0(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL3(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL3(EVAL3(EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL4(EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__)))

#define MAP_END(...)
#define MAP_OUT

#define MAP_GET_END2() 0, MAP_END
#define MAP_GET_END1(...) MAP_GET_END2
#define MAP_GET_END(...) MAP_GET_END1
#define MAP_NEXT0(test, next, ...) next MAP_OUT
#define MAP_NEXT1(test, next) MAP_NEXT0(test, next, 0)
#define MAP_NEXT(test, next)  MAP_NEXT1(MAP_GET_END test, next)

#define MAP0(f, x, peek, ...) f(x) MAP_NEXT(peek, MAP1)(f, peek, __VA_ARGS__)
#define MAP1(f, x, peek, ...) f(x) MAP_NEXT(peek, MAP0)(f, peek, __VA_ARGS__)

#define MAP(f, ...) EVAL(MAP1(f, __VA_ARGS__, ()()(), ()()(), ()()(), 0))

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

typedef int (*rx_run_fn)();

struct rx__data {
    const char *name;
    int value;
    rx_run_fn run;
};

int run() { return 999; }

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define RX__WRAP_ASSIGNMENT(x) out x;
#define RX__MAKE_DATA(...)                                                     \
    []() -> struct rx__data {                                                  \
        struct rx__data out = {};                                              \
        MAP(RX__WRAP_ASSIGNMENT, __VA_ARGS__);                                 \
        return out;                                                            \
    }()
#else
#define RX__MAKE_DATA(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }
#endif

static const struct rx__data foo
    = RX__MAKE_DATA(.name = "abc", .value = 123, .run = run);
```

It's all good except that, since the `rx__data` struct can be attached to both test suites and test cases, I'd like to have a mechanism that allows me to know if a data member has been explicitely set or not by the user. This way, I can infer the final data to apply to a test case by:

- retrieving the data to inherit from the parent test suite.
- overriding only the members from the test suite that were explicitely set onto the test case.

For example

```c
RX_TEST_SUITE(my_suite, .name = "abc", .value = 123, .run = run);

RX_TEST_CASE(my_suite, my_case, .value = 666)
{
    ...
}
```

would result in ‘my_case’ having the data `{.name = "abc", .value = 666, .run = run}` attached to it.

For this to work, I thought of adding a boolean value for each field, to keep track of what has been explicitely defined or not by the user:

```c
typedef int (*rx_run_fn)();

struct rx__data {
    const char *name;
    int value;
    rx_run_fn run;

    int name_defined;
    int value_defined;
    int run_defined;
};

int run() { return 999; }

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define RX__ARG(field, value) out.field = value; out.field##_defined = 1
#define RX__MAKE_DATA(...)                                                     \
    []() -> struct rx__data {                                                  \
        struct rx__data out = {};                                              \
        __VA_ARGS__;                                                           \
        return out;                                                            \
    }();
#else
#define RX__ARG(field, value) .field = value, .field##_defined = 1
#define RX__MAKE_DATA(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }
#endif

#define RX_NAME_ARG(x) RX__ARG(name, x)
#define RX_VALUE_ARG(x) RX__ARG(value, x)
#define RX_RUN_ARG(x) RX__ARG(run, x)

static const struct rx__data foo
    = RX__MAKE_DATA(RX_NAME_ARG("abc"), RX_VALUE_ARG(123), RX_RUN_ARG(run));
```

And it's all working great here again, except that the user now has to set the arguments using macros instead of the previous designated initializer syntax.

So the questions is: how can I keep track of these user-defined `struct` members while preserving the designated initializer syntax?

Note: if possible, I'd really like to have a robust way of detecting if a member was defined, so no in-band indicators—that is, no ”if this member has this magic value, then it's likely that is wasn't explicitely set”.

Answer (score 1):

Just found my own answer, thanks rubber duck!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#define EXPAND(x) x

#define ARG_IDX(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8,  n, ...) n
#define COUNT_ARGS(...) EXPAND(ARG_IDX(__VA_ARGS__, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0))

#define CONCAT_0(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_0(a, b)

#define APPLY_0(x)
#define APPLY_1(x, _1) \
    x(_1)
#define APPLY_2(x, _1, _2) \
    x(_1) x(_2)
#define APPLY_3(x, _1, _2, _3) \
    x(_1) x(_2) x(_3)
#define APPLY_4(x, _1, _2, _3, _4) \
    x(_1) x(_2) x(_3) x(_4)
#define APPLY_5(x, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5) \
    x(_1) x(_2) x(_3) x(_4) x(_5)
#define APPLY_6(x, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6) \
    x(_1) x(_2) x(_3) x(_4) x(_5) x(_6)
#define APPLY_7(x, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7) \
    x(_1) x(_2) x(_3) x(_4) x(_5) x(_6) x(_7)
#define APPLY_8(x, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8) \
    x(_1) x(_2) x(_3) x(_4) x(_5) x(_6) x(_7) x(_8)

#define APPLY(x, ...) EXPAND(x(__VA_ARGS__))
#define MAP(x, ...) \
    EXPAND(APPLY(CONCAT(APPLY_, COUNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)), x, __VA_ARGS__))

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

typedef int (*rx_run_fn)();

int run() { return 999; }

#ifdef __cplusplus
struct rx__data {
    struct {
        const char *name;
        double number;
        rx_run_fn run;
    } value;

    struct {
        int name;
        int number;
        int run;
    } defined;
};
#define RX__WRAP_ASSIGNMENT(x) out.value x; out.defined x ? 1 : 1;
#define RX__MAKE_DATA(...)                                                     \
    []() -> struct rx__data {                                                  \
        struct rx__data out = {};                                              \
        MAP(RX__WRAP_ASSIGNMENT, __VA_ARGS__);                                 \
        return out;                                                            \
    }()
#define RX__GET_ARG_VALUE(data, field) data . value . field
#define RX__IS_ARG_DEFINED(data, field) data . defined . field
#else
struct rx__data {
    const char *name;
    int name_defined;
    double number;
    int number_defined;
    rx_run_fn run;
    int run_defined;
};
#define RX__WRAP_ASSIGNMENT(x) x, 1,
#define RX__MAKE_DATA(...) { MAP(RX__WRAP_ASSIGNMENT, __VA_ARGS__) }
#define RX__GET_ARG_VALUE(data, field) data . field
#define RX__IS_ARG_DEFINED(data, field) data . field##_defined
#endif

static const struct rx__data foo = RX__MAKE_DATA(
    .name = "abc", .number = 1.23, .run = run);

int
main(void)
{
    if (RX__IS_ARG_DEFINED(foo, name)) {
        printf("name   : %s\n", RX__GET_ARG_VALUE(foo, name));
    } else {
        printf("name   : (not defined)\n");
    }

    if (RX__IS_ARG_DEFINED(foo, number)) {
        printf("number : %f\n", RX__GET_ARG_VALUE(foo, number));
    } else {
        printf("number : (not defined)\n");
    }

    if (RX__IS_ARG_DEFINED(foo, run)) {
        printf("run    : %d\n", RX__GET_ARG_VALUE(foo, run)());
    } else {
        printf("run    : (not defined)\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```